# Why is this not a counter example to the completeness of the space of continuous bounded functions on [0,1]

Tags: functional-analysis

I heard that the space of continuous bounded functions defined over $[0,1]$ is complete, and there is even proofs of that.

But consider this sequence : $f_n$ has as a graph the "triangle" with vertices $(-1/n, 1/n, 1)$ (? n.d.r.)

The sequence converges towards the indicator of the set $\{1\}$ which is not continuous.

Comment: The convergence doesn't seem to be uniform. You have to take into account the norm with respect to which your sequence converges (or not).

Comment: Your f_n are not even defined on [0,1].

Comment: I do not understand what $f_n$ is.  What is the triplet (-1/n,1/n,1)? and in what way are those the vertices of a triangle?

Answer (score 5):

*Your description of $f_n$ is kind of garbled - I assume you want $f_n(x)=0$ for $x\in [0, 1-{1\over n}]$, and for the graph of $f_n$ on $[1-{1\over n}, 1]$ to be a straight line connecting $(1-{1\over n}, 0)$ to $(1, 1)$.*

The space of continuous functions defined over $[0, 1]$ is indeed complete - *under the right topology or metric*. Namely, the *sup metric*: $d(f, g)=\sup\{\vert f(x)-g(x)\vert: x\in[0, 1]\}$.

Your sequence is not Cauchy in the sup metric, even though it does converge pointwise! For example, $d(f_n, f_{2n})={1\over 2}$. This is a good exercise (HINT: show that $f_n(1-{1\over 2n})={1\over 2}$, but $f_{2n}(1-{1\over 2n})=0$), and shows that under the sup metric your sequence is not Cauchy.